# Custom PreferenceCategory cut off at bottom of preference list

Tags: android, preferences

I extended from `PreferenceCategory` so I can change its text color to red (see screenshot). But as it turned out, the last Preference field isn't shown anymore, it's cut off at the bottom. I indicated in red where the preference should be displayed.

[image]

As you can see in my implementation, I didn't override anything else:

```
public class PreferenceCategoryDangerZone extends PreferenceCategory {

    public PreferenceCategoryDangerZone(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PreferenceCategoryDangerZone(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PreferenceCategoryDangerZone(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    // Tried both with and without this constructor, but same result
    @TargetApi(21)
    public PreferenceCategoryDangerZone(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        titleView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ...

    <com.mohoff.leapp.ui.components.settings.PreferenceCategoryDangerZone
        android:title="@string/setting_cat_danger_zone_title"
        android:key="@string/setting_cat_danger_zone">

        <Preference android:title="@string/setting_delete_timeslots_title"
                    android:key="@string/setting_delete_timeslots"/>
        <Preference android:title="@string/setting_delete_zones_title"
                    android:key="@string/setting_delete_zones"/>
        <Preference android:title="@string/setting_clean_map_title"
                    android:summary="@string/setting_clean_map_summary"
                    android:key="@string/setting_clean_map"/>
    </com.mohoff.leapp.ui.components.settings.PreferenceCategoryDangerZone>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When I am using the default `PreferenceCategory` it works perfectly. I tried to add a `Preference` below `PreferenceCategoryDangerZone`. As a result the whole category was displayed correctly but the newly added last element remained cut off.

Any ideas on what went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Show us the xml file as well

Comment: Added it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Does PreferenceCategoryDangerZone inherit from something particular such as PreferenceCategory?

Comment: `public class PreferenceCategoryDangerZone extends PreferenceCategory { ... }` , so yes.